# Showing a bitmap in dataGridView using C#

Tags: c#, image

I want to show in dataGridView some image. I have two components, dataGridView, dataTable and one Bitmap. DataTable has two columns.

```
dataGridview.source = dataTable;
```

Now, I want to show in dataGridView three columns, two from dataTable and new third with my bitmap. If it is easier, I can modify dataTable and dataGridView.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways you can approach this.

There is an image column type for the DataGridView, the DataGridViewImageColumn, which has an image property that you can pass a bitmap to.

Something like the following should work:

```
private void createGraphicsColumn(Bitmap image)
{
    DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    imageColumn.Image = image;
    imageColumn.Name = "Tree";
    imageColumn.HeaderText = "Nice tree";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2, imageColumn);
}
```

You can also set the Value property of individual cells in this column if needed.

The example above plus a whole lot of other discussion can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ab8kd75.aspx).

---

Another option is to add your image into the datatable - this will automatically generate your image column, but the new column in the datatable needs to be of type byte array.

I found the following code to do this with a quick google:

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return  ms.ToArray();
}
```

If you do take this approach I'd suggest doing a little research to find the best method of creating the byte array - I couldn't vouch for that code being the best.

Comment: thanks very much for help, I think that now I'll be able to finish this problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply create datatable with image column and add image to it

```
dtMain.Columns.Add("ImageColumn", typeof(Image));
dtMain.Rows.Add(Image.FromFile(photopath + "1.jpg"));
```

Download full code at http://tablegridview.blogspot.in

Comment: That is not working for me, Exception:
Convertion of System.type to String not possible.
...Columns.Add("Goto",typeof(Image));