# System.byte[] to datagrid

Tags: vb.net

I have saved some DataGridViewImage column to sql after converting them to Binary data. I need to write them back to my datagridview control. here is part of the code . when I run this code I got error "invalid Parameter" any idea ?  Thanks

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cmdselect As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblImgData", _Connection)
    _Connection.Open()
    Try
        Using dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdselect)
            Using commandBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter)
                Dim dataTable As New DataTable()
                dataTable.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)
                For x = 0 To (dataTable.DefaultView.Count - 1)
                    Dim barrImg As Byte() = DirectCast(dataTable.Rows(x).Item(1), Byte())
                    dataTable.Rows(x).Item(1) = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(barrImg))
                Next
                Dim bindingSource1 As New BindingSource()
                bindingSource1.DataSource = dataTable
                DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Connection error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
        ' finish the program   
        Application.[Exit]()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't mark vb.net questions as C#, thank you.

Comment: I guess everybody on vacation:)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Did you see this by any chance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317250/showing-a-bitmap-in-datagridview-using-c-sharp