# Display an image in DataGridView in C# from SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to display an image in a `DataGridView` in a Windows Forms application from a SQL Server database.

In the database the image is stored as `byte[]` so I want to put it in data table and display it in a `DataGridView`:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select PKID,Names,Position,picture  from Delegation where PKID='" + id + "'", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter dr = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

dr.Fill(dt);
datagrideview1.datasource = dt;
```

So in the `DataGridView` it displays `ID,name,position` but the picture is not displayed, so what do I do?

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injections - please make sure that you don't concatenate your SQL statement and use parameters instead.

Comment: Do you know how to convert a byte array to an image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317250/showing-a-bitmap-in-datagridview-using-c-sharp/6317332#6317332

Answer (score 0):

Here is an MSDN article on using a DataGridViewImageColumn

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Code sample is pretty huge so I've refrained from posting it in its entirety, here a good representative sample I think:

```
 private void CreateColumns()
    {
        DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn;
        int columnCount = 0;
        do
        {
            Bitmap unMarked = blank;
            imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();

            //Add twice the padding for the left and  
            //right sides of the cell.
            imageColumn.Width = x.Width + 2 * bitmapPadding + 1;

            imageColumn.Image = unMarked;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(imageColumn);
            columnCount = columnCount + 1;
        }
        while (columnCount < 3);
    }
```

Essentially you create an image column and then just bind the appropriate data to it. In this case it would be a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Getting data from database is straightforward. Real challange here is to setup datagridview so it can show image.

You will have to add a column which can show images. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6317332/443244). It will help you to get the desired output.

There is an `image` column type for the `DataGridView`, the `DataGridViewImageColumn`, which has an image property that you can pass a bitmap to.

Answer (score 0):

I Found The Answer may be data Gride View not show Image because i have problem in my data base so i clear all Columns  and it work and the secret to view any image in data gride view first convert image to byte[] and insert it in data base after that call the byte[] from data base in data table and it work