# How do I show a picture in a chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, system.drawing

I want to show a picture in a chart. A `DataTable` is the `DataSource` of the chart.

I tried this code:

```
data.Columns.Add("Image", typeof(byte[]));
DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"Chart.jpg");
dr["Image"] = imageToByteArray(img);

public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

And also:

```
  data.Columns.Add("Image", typeof(Image));
  DataRow dr = data.NewRow();
  Image img = Image.FromFile(@"Chart.jpg");
  dr["Image"] = img;
```

But only the text: System.Drawing.Bitmap will be shown.

Comment: Is `data` a `DataGridView`, and is that what you mean by _"chart"_? (I assumed the most likely scenario when I retagged this question, but would like to make sure.)

Comment: What chart? How do you add it? Post that code.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317250/showing-a-bitmap-in-datagridview-using-c-sharp; see also [this MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/de-de/b5ba14d3-4609-4a5d-9e56-1ece5dfaac9b/bitmap-in-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols).

Comment: The chart is an Organisation Chart.

Comment: Page.Controls.Add(mychart); mychart.DataSource = data; mychart.DataBind();

Comment: And data is a DataTable

Answer (score 0):

I think you should to change column type to byte:

System.Byte[]

```
data.Columns.Add("Image", Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"));
DataRow dr = data.NewRow();
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"Chart.jpg");
dr["Image"] = imageToByteArray(img);
```

Comment: Does this actually work? I wonder why the column has data type `Image`, but an actual value of `byte[]`…?

Comment: No i get an error: System.Byte and Image here: dr["Image"] = img;

Comment: Excuse me, i forgot to change column type, answer edited, test it, i hope it works fine

Comment: With your Code i get an error, that the two types are diffrent. I think you mean: data.Columns.Add("Image",typeof(Byte[]));